# VBA Using regex for replacing stuff

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I never did VBA before, and I am not skilled in programming in any way xD
I am trying do remove some things from a list that contains html descriptions, but it is not working.

Any advice what horrible things I did wrong here?

```
Function entferne_sonstige_zeichen(description)

entferne_sonstige_zeichen = description

Dim oRegExp As RegExp
Set oRegExp = New RegExp
With oRegExp
.IgnoreCase = False
.Global = True
.MultiLine = True
.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z\d,/-]"
End With

Dim ReplacePattern As String
ReplacePattern = ""

description = oRegExp.Replace(ReplacePattern)

End Function
```

Comment: In what way is it failing?

Comment: You need to show the text before the replace and what you expect to see after, as well as describe what is failing.  Throw us a bone.

Comment: I have a html description that can contain symboles like %#§" and I try to delete them with this function using regex

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
Function entferne_sonstige_zeichen(str As String) As String

Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z\d,/-]"
    .ignorecase = True
    entferne_sonstige_zeichen = .Replace(str, vbNullString)
End With

End Function
```